# on_raw_reaction_add(payload) troubleshooting

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey i am developing a Discord Bot with Python.
Here is the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

This program should give a user a role if he or she reacts to a message

I tried to define the ctx in the function itself

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    member = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members())
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == "check-in", ctx.guild.roles)
    check_in = ["612637944544624690"]
    if str(payload.channel_id) in check_in:
        await client.add_roles(member, role, reason="check-in")
```

That is the error without ctx in the function itself:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaitr\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/kaitr/PycharmProjects/Discord Tutorial/bot.py", line 39, in on_raw_reaction_add
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == "check-in", ctx.guild.roles)
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

That is the error with ctx in the function itself:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaitr\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have access to an [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) because this isn't a command.  You can only use the attributes of the payload, a [`RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) object.  This includes a `guild_id` attribute that you can use to get the guild:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.guild_id is None:
        return  # Reaction is on a private message
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="check-in")
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    if str(payload.channel_id) in check_in:
        await member.add_roles(role, reason="check-in")
```

Comment: i updated member.add_roles(guild, payload.user_id, role, reason="check-in")
now i get that problem:

discord.errors.NotFound: 404 NOT FOUND (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
but the name of the role is there. I also tried the id directly but also this problem came up

Comment: Did you try with the code I posted?  The change in your comment doesn't make sense. You should look at the documentation for `add_roles`

Comment: i tryed with your code and it makes sense to me. The add_roles need a guild_id, user_id, role_id (which i should get trough role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="check_in"))  and a reason. Somehow he don't like the role or perhaps the guild is wrong

Comment: Add_roles just needs the Role objects, which is what you get from guild.roles https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles